# Coupon code invalid

Tags: coupon

Trying to add a new 10% off on orders over £800 coupon to our site (v.1.7.0.2) and I keep getting the following message: "Coupon code "10off" is not valid."

If I remove the subtotal over 800 condition it applies fine.

Please can someone give me a clue why this might be happening?

Comment: I may ask a stupid question...but did you test with the cart subtotal over 800?

Comment: Hi Marius, I did try that yes.

Comment: Has anyone else experienced issues with coupon codes not being valid before? Would appreciate even just a point in the right direction as I'm at a real dead end with this now.

Comment: one more question. is GBP the only currency in your store? If not, what's your  base currency, and what's the currency you are using on frontend when adding the coupon? Keep in mind that the values you enter in the backend are in the base currency.

Comment: British Pound Sterling and this is the only currency allowed.

Comment: Please post the details of the rules that you have created.

Comment: What are the condition exactly? Can you post screenshot of that rule section?

Answer (score -3):

Try to set the 'user per customer = 100 or blank'. I got the same problem before and it solve it.